# Pickling/unpickling alternative (API-compatible) class implementations

Tags: python, c++, alias, pickle

In a distributed computing project, we are using Pyro to pass objects over the wire between nodes; Pyro internally serializes and deserializes objects using pickle.

Some classes in the project have two implementations: one pure-Python (for ease of installation, especially for Windows users), one in c++/boost::python (much faster, but requires boost + knowledge of how to compile the extension module). Both python and c++ classes support pickling (in c++, that is done via boost::python).

These classes have different fully-qualified name (`mupif.Octree.Octant` vs. `mupif.fastOctant.Octant`), but the latter is aliased to the former and overwrites the pure-Python definition (`mupif.Octree.Octant=mupif.fastOctant.Octant`), so it is transparent to the user and the fast variant is always used if available on the node.

However, pickle uses `__module__` and `__class__` to identify the instance, thus when the c++-based object is passed over the wire to another node which does not support it, unpickling will fail.

What is a solution to this? Is it acceptable to change the classe's `__module__`, i.e. `foo.fastOctant.Octant.__class__.__module__='mupif.Octree'`? Can it have some side-effects I don't see yet?

Comment: Does it help to alias in another way (fast = normal) if there is no fast implementation available? Maybe this could be done only for the time of unpickling and then reversed?

Comment: Simple, elegant! Can you post as anwer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help to alias in another way (fast = normal) if there is no fast implementation available? Maybe this could be done only for the time of unpickling and then reversed, to avoid confusing checks in other code?